# How can i get the width when i use v-for in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have some data to show by v-for, I want to get the width of each elements.

In mounted, I used `this.$refs.name.offsetWidth`, but it was always be 0, how can i do

```
mounted(){
  ipcRenderer.on('getVuexMsg', (e, data) => {
    this.barrageList.push(data)
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.$refs.text[0].offsetWidth);
    },2000)
  })
}

<div class="textArea" ref="textArea">
  <div class="text" v-for="(item,index) in barrageList" :key="index" ref="text">{{ item.content }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code so that we can understand the question in more detail

Comment: Please provide the code example and the vue version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide much information but there could be an issue that you are trying to access the elements before they are loaded into the DOM.

You should use `nextTick` for that. According to its definition-

> If you want to catch the moment when DOM has just been updated, then
> you need to use a special function nextTick(callback). It executes
> callback right after the new data updates have reached DOM.

Here is a demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      barrageList: [{
          content: "Hello World"
        },
        {
          content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing."
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$refs.text[1].offsetWidth);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="textArea" ref="textArea">
    <div class="text" v-for="(item,index) in barrageList" :key="index" ref="text">{{ item.content }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```